# Hang on CreateService when windows is starting

Tags: c++, service

I register my program as a windows service. When I reboot the windows, the service will be START_PENDING forever. 
After I traced, I found it hung on CreateService function.

```
hService=CreateService( hSCManager,
                            pszDriverName,
                            pszDriverName,
                            SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
                            SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,
                            SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
                            SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
                            pszDriverPath,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            NULL);
```

I can resolve the problem by creating the service before rebooting, but I want to know what the hang happened. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: By the way, my program will create a driver as a service. It will create, open, close, and delete at runtime. The problem hangs on creating the driver as a service when rebooting. 
In order to resolve the problem, I will register the driver service in installer. But I still want to know the root cause.

Comment: When do you call CreateService()?  If I recall correctly there is a service database lock in play.  I think Windows has the lock while starting a service, so you deadlock when trying to modify the service database (by creating another service) unless you indicate to SCM that you've started.  At least it's something like that; I don't remember the exact details off the top of my head.

Comment: My program call Service A. It will load a driver as Service B at runtime. When the system is rebooting, the Service A hangs on CreateService() with START_PENDING status. 
I try to create the Service B in installer, but Service A hangs on StartService() now.

Comment: At last, I created the Service B with automatic startup type and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well, services must be created only once. You don't have to call the CreateService function again ever ! And I wouldn't recommend to create it while in the Windows boot process.

As you can see in the following MSDN example, you have to start the given example software with "install" command line argument to create the service. In any other case the service is considered as installed.

Notice in the example the use of StartServiceCtrlDispatcher function to launch the service main function (In this case SvcMain).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: My friend also recommend me not create the service many times. I will resolve the problem by installer. Do you know the root cause for the hang?

Answer (score 0):

Applications which have services usually have an installer which registers and installs their services. When you install an application , all services are made and registered and there is no need to install them again while booting the system. Windows executes this function as a regular function while starting the service.

The function which you have mentioned above is used for service installation in installers when a new service should be created.

Comment: I will resolve the problem by installer. Do you know the root cause for the hang?

Comment: It can be complicated. Honestly I didn't tried to install a service while windows is booting. Since it is not common the consequences are not clear. I should test it myself to see the result, your project is in C++, right ?

Comment: In the fact, my project is in java. I register the java program as a service by java service wrapper. The program will load a driver as a service at runtime by JNA. I'm not sure whether it happens on pure C++ code.